# How do I set the timeout on Knex query?

Tags: knex.js

I tried editing the query directly, like this:

```
knex.schema
  .table("users", function(table) {
    table.timestamp("created_at");
  })
  .timeout(5, { cancel: true })
```

That got me just a Javascript error, no such function.

I tried altering the knexfile:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "postgresql",
    dialect: "postgres",
    connection: {
      timeout: 10,
      database: "thedb"
    },
    ...
```

It didn't complain about the change, but when I went directly to `psql` and locked the table, then tried to alter the table through Knex, it just hung indefinitely, exactly the thing I was trying to avoid.

Comment: what db are you connecting in knexConfig file?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 -- it's Postgres database named `thedb`.  I know the file is being read, because if I change that name to something, it complains.

Comment: checked the document, saying that this ```timeout``` function is only supported in MySQL and PostgreSQL. So it may probably not related to db issue. However, I doubt that if ```timeout``` can be used when you use schema builder like this. ```timeout``` function is located under query builder. More ref here. http://knexjs.org/